# Can't seem to get the regex pattern right

Tags: php, regex

I need to check a string for a certain string, I want to use regex for this, but the more I keep trying, the more it confuses (and frustrates) me; I can't seem to get it right.

I need the expression to return true when the string contains something like this: `[[module:instance]]`, but it needs to meet the following conditions:

- Always open with 2 brackets `[[`
- After the two brackets the string can contain everything except for `:`, and has no limit to it's length
- After the string 1 `:` character must be present
- After the `:` again a string that can contain everything except a `:`, and has no limit to it's length
- Always close with 2 brackets `]]`

Any help, tips, good tutorials, anything would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a comment - measure speed of execution of the regex and try to do the same without regex. I have a feeling that the straightforward variant without regex can be faster.

Comment: What should be matched in `[[a[[b:c]]d]]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/\[\[[^:]+?:[^:]+?]]/', $str, $match)
```

An explanation:

- **`\[\[`** matches the literal `[[`
- **`[^:]+?`** matches anything but `:` (non-greedy)
- **`:`** matches the literal `:`
- **`[^:]+?`** matches anything but `:` (non-greedy)
- **`]]`** matches the literal `]]`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Accepted because of (clear) explanation (nice to be knowing what and how I'm doing it! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: why do you use \\[\\[ to match the literal [[ at the beginning but use ]] to match ]] at the end? Just trying to learn...not questioning the accuracy of your answer...

Comment: @Remnant: You have escape the open brackets at the beginning, otherwise they'll be interpreted as the start of a character class. Whereas the close bracket doesn't have any special meaning outside of a character class and doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @Remnant: A literal `[` is the character class open delimiter. So `[[` needs to be escaped: `\[\[`. But the closing `]` does not need to be escaped as it is only character class close delimiters if there’s an open character class. So `]` needs to be escaped in `[abc\]]` to have a character class consisting of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `]`. But `\[]` is the literal `[]`.

Comment: / @Anon - thanks for that. Makes sense. Just started to read Mastering Regular Expressions by Friedl and using regex questions on SO to help my learning...good to see some practical examples and get the logic behind them

Answer (score 2):

```
\[\[[^:]+:[^:]+\]\]
```

Explanation:

`\[\[` matches two opening brackets.

`[^:]` matches any **one** character except for a colon.

`[^:]+` matches **one or more** characters except for colons.

Comment: This will also match `[[a[[b:c]]d]]`.

Comment: @Gumbo and this will be ok: string 1 and string 2 are allowed to contain anything but semicolon, and this allows double brackets.

Comment: @Gumbo It will. But the asker never said that it shouldn't :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your regex:

```
\[\[.*?:[^:]*?\]\]
```

The backslashes are needed before the square brackets because they're metacharacters like ., * and ?.

Comment: This will also match `[[::::module:]]` , won't it?

Comment: No.  The non-greedy match at the first will stop once the first `:` is reached, the middle `:` is required, and the last group matches everything *but* `:`.  However, [[:]] does match (not sure if the OP wants that or not).

Answer (score 0):

How about `\[\[[^:]+\:[^:]+\]\]`? Does that work?

It should match two literal `[` characters, then any character that is not `:` repeated at least once, then a `:`, then any character that is not `:` at least once, then two literal `]` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work ?

[[[^:]*:{1}[^:]*]]